# Compare incomparable features. Grammar

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, grammaticality-in-context

I want to compare the features of a single person.
The following sentence should describe a person. The person is very clever but at the same time, this person is insane. I mean this madness in his had helps him to be genius and the madness is more positive than negative.

> **He is as clever (genius) as he is insane.**

And I'm not sure that sentence above is correct.

What grammar structure should I use to compare incomparable things of one person?
Should I use any phraseology in this case?

Comment: *as clever **a** genius as he is insane* would be how you would include the noun **genius** in the comparison, although it is a little awkward when compared to **as he is insane**.  *He's as big a fool as he is generous.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compare the degrees of various qualities, and say they are equal, e.g. 'He is as clever as he is insane', 'my car is as efficient as it is stylish', 'my cousin is as stupid as he is ugly'. The implication is usually that both qualities are strongly, notably or definitely held.

[As... as (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-as)